# How do I get the browser-frame height and width, like in this example?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've been seeing this done more and more around the Web, and I don't know what exactly this technique is called so I have had a hard time searching for it. It's basically how you have the first section that is the full width and height of the frame, but you can still scroll down and see more stuff.

Here's one example where this happens:
http://ideaware.co/

Can it be done in just HTML and CSS? Is there Javascript involved?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer is partially correct, but there is a JS component to this as well.  The page you referenced makes use of jQuery which allows for functions like the following:

```
function sizebanner() {
windowHeight = $(window).height();
windowWidth = $(window).width();
var bannerHeight = $(".banner > div").height();

if (windowWidth >= 768) {
    $(".banner.home, .banner.project").css({ 'height' : windowHeight + "px"});
    $(".banner.home > div, .banner.project > div").not(".imgproject").css('padding-top', parseInt((windowHeight - bannerHeight) / 2));
} else if (windowWidth >= 480 ) {
    $(".banner.home, .banner.project").css('height','485px'); 
    $(".banner.home > div").css('padding-top','183px');
    $(".banner.project > div").not(".imgproject").css('padding-top','150px');
} 
else {
    $(".banner.home").css('height','312px'); 
    $(".banner.home > div").css('padding-top','105px');
    $(".banner.project").css('height','420px'); 
    $(".banner.project > div").not(".imgproject").css('padding-top','105px');
} 
};
```

This function dynamically resizes the content of the banner div for preset screen size groups.  There is much more to this, so I would suggest you inspect the page source and reverse engineer it a little to get your answer.  I find that if I come across something in a webpage that I genuinely like, I hit F12 in IE or open te dev tools in Chrome or use Firebug in Firefox to inspect the page source and see how it was done.  That is my suggestion to you.  Inspect the page and discern for yourself the method that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's applying the following background size to the opening <section>:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

More details on this technique can be found here: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give 100% width to first div and then 80% width to othe divs so first one is in full window

example :

```
<div style="width:100%">
/* full length contain  */
</div>

<div style="width:80%">
/* small length contain  */
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For doing this thing you need to reset your css

For example

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

You need not to use the same, you can create your own css resets, depending upon which elements you will be using.

Now take a look at the following html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style type="text/css"> 
html,body
{
margin:0px;
paddng:0px;
height:100%;
Width:100%;
background-color:black;
vertical-align: baseline;
}

#browserSize
{
color:White;
background-color:blue;
font-size:25px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="browserSize">
This goes to full extent of browser window
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can save the code above in a html file see it on a browser.

I have simply cleared the margins and paddings for the Html and body
and the main div(browser) is extended into full browser.